# Android ShareActionProvider with ViewPager forces me save Image

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, shareactionprovider

I have a big issue with `ShareActionProvider`. My application is like a gallery application using `ViewPager`, that keeps track of favorite image items, and gives possibility to share them through `ShareActionProvider`. 
Everything works fine except that whichever image I scroll to is saved in the directory I use to get Uri.

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragement_gallery, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    favoriteItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.idItemFavoris);

    MenuItem item = (MenuItem) mMenu.findItem(R.id.idItemShashare);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

    initShareIntent();
}

private void initShareIntent() {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(mCurrentImage);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");

        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    if(imageView != null){
        Drawable mDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
              mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        return uri;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I need to call

```
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

each time I instatiate the view in the ViewPager

```
class GalleryViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listeOfPhotos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        mPhoto = listeOfPhotos.get(position);

        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .displayImage(mPhoto.getUrl(), mCurrentImage, FragmentGallery.options, null, null);

        container.addView(mCurrentImage, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //Change the Favorite Icon and Invalidate Menu
        initIconFavorite();

        return mCurrentView;
    }

}
```

I would be glad if you guys help me with this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `initShareIntent` which calls eventually `getLocalBitmapUri` in every `Fragment` of yours. That is the one that creates a separate image in the gallery.

I would suggest you that to stop using `ShareActionProvider`. Google stopped using it in their applications. With `ShareActionProvider` you have know the URI and the sharing Intent before user want to share it and clicks the share button. So it becomes a little bit hard to do.

You can checkout the below links for how to do that. You basically have to generate the sharing Intent when the button is clicked instead of in `onCreate` callback. 
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

If you use normal ActionBar button and fire sharing dialog yourself, you can call and create the local `Bitmap` using `getLocalBitmapUri` only when the user wants to share the image.

If you must use `ShareActionProvider`, you shouldn't recreate a new local `Bitmap`. Even when you show an online image, you cache it somewhere right. A local copy of the image is already out there somewhere. You should find it and give it to the `ShareActionProvider` as an URI. Of course, it should be publicly accessible. So you can set your image cache folder somewhere in public folders like sdcard etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tought of your third solution by using Universal Image Loader which would do the work for me. But I would like to explore the other idea of using my own button in ActionBarSupport, so do you have any idea how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use ShareActionProvider, you shouldn't recreate a new local Bitmap. Even when you show an online image, you cache it somewhere right. A local copy of the image is already out there somewhere. You should find it and give it to the ShareActionProvider as an URI. Of course, it should be publicly accessible. So you can set your image cache folder somewhere in public folders like sdcard etc.